# Better quality image from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm currently using **UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()** to save a content's image to a user's camera roll, but the image quality is worse than if I do a screen shot in the simulator. Is there any way to improve it? And what format the saved image is in anyway? Bmp? Is there any way to change this?

Here's my save code:

```
CGSize size = [content bounds].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[[content layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *originalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(originalImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: how big is your "`size`"?  if it's not really that big, then your resolution will be quite poor.

Comment: It is about the same size of the screen. I'm not viewing the saved image elsewhere. I saved it on the simulator and went to simulator's camera roll and it looks a lot worse than in the app.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` you should be using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
```

Comment: I believe it saves as jpg.

Comment: This just makes the image render with the correct conrentscale. The 0 is the default (equals to `[UIScreen mainscreen] scale`). To save as JPG or PNG use UIImageJPGRepresentation or UimagePNGRepresentation on the resulting image.

Comment: But doesn't that give me NSData? Do I start a new image with that data and then save that image to the camera roll? Sounds awfully complicated...

Comment: You can write the image data to the library with `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Comment: Why would this save a white image when using device, but works on simulator ?

Comment: @Smick you probably need to create a question and show your code.

Comment: @Wain done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681147/screenshots-on-device-vs-simulator/22681332?noredirect=1#22681332

Answer (score 0):

If you're on retina display the size of the context is only half the size of the "real" image.

Try to double the size (or to be correct use the contentScaleFactor of the view).

Comment: Yep, that appears to be the problem. How do I use the contentScaleFactor to scale up the output image?