# Screenshots on Device vs Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, screenshot

Why would does this work on simulator but not on a device.

I am trying to capture a screenshot of a view that contains more than one AVPlayer.I can snap a frame from a player, but I need the actual screenshot as the view contains a few players, in specific locations on the screen at once.

There are multiple threads regarding this topic, but I am yet to find an answer.

```
- (UIImage *) takeScreenShot
{
    UIImage *image;
    CGSize snapArea = self.view.bounds.size;
    int bottomTobBarHeight = 44;
    snapArea.height = snapArea.height - bottomTobBarHeight;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snapArea, YES, 1.0);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: for capturing avplayer screen please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388226/get-the-screenshot-of-a-streaming-video-on-iphone

Comment: Got it to work, I took a screenshot using above to get a blank canvas, then drew each UIImage obtained from the AVPlayer one other the other, using the AVPlayers position on the screen. Will share code asap