# Blurry Image on converting view into UIImage - Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've converted a view to UIImage but image quality is not good. Is there any way to increase the quality of an image or any other way to convert view into image with keeping quality.

Code for converting View into UIImage

```
var Sharecell = ExplorertableView.CellAt(indexPath);
UIImage image;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.ContentView.Frame.Size);
Sharecell.ContentView.Layer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
var items = new Foundation.NSObject[] { image };
UIActivityViewController activity = new UIActivityViewController(items, null);
this.PresentViewController(activity, true, null);
```

Comment: Try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030323/better-quality-image-from-uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext

Comment: Thanx, this help me for increasing the quality of image by scaling its image